# Errores por no linkear las librerías openssl al usar gloox

Tags: c++, codeblocks, openssl

Estoy usando `gloox` y para hacer mi extensión la comunicación irá cifrada por lo que necesito `openssl`, al compilar obtengo el siguiente error:

```
||=== Build: Debug in main (compiler: GNU GCC Compiler) ===|
C:\Users\Androide\Desktop\gloox\libgloox.a(clientbase.o):clientbase.cpp|| undefined reference to `FreeCredentialsHandle@4'|
C:\Users\Androide\Desktop\gloox\libgloox.a(clientbase.o):clientbase.cpp|| undefined reference to `DeleteSecurityContext@4'|
C:\Users\Androide\Desktop\gloox\libgloox.a(clientbase.o):clientbase.cpp|| undefined reference to `FreeCredentialsHandle@4'|
C:\Users\Androide\Desktop\gloox\libgloox.a(clientbase.o):clientbase.cpp|| undefined reference to `DeleteSecurityContext@4'|
C:\Users\Androide\Desktop\gloox\libgloox.a(clientbase.o):clientbase.cpp|| undefined reference to `AcquireCredentialsHandleW@36'|
C:\Users\Androide\Desktop\gloox\libgloox.a(clientbase.o):clientbase.cpp|| undefined reference to `InitializeSecurityContextA@48'|
||error: ld returned 1 exit status|
||=== Build failed: 7 error(s), 0 warning(s) (0 minute(s), 2 second(s)) ===|
```

Estoy usando como IDE `Codeblocks`(mingw) pero de momento no sé como incluir la librería `openssl` a mi proyecto para solucionar los errores mencionados.

Mi extensión:

```
#include "gloox/src/client.h"
#include "gloox/src/messagehandler.h"
#include "gloox/src/message.h"
#include "gloox/src/presencehandler.h"
#include "gloox/src/connectionlistener.h"
#include <ctime>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;
using namespace gloox;
//my one
const string LOGIN = "gmail.com";
ostream& operator<<(ostream& os, Message::MessageType type) {
    switch (type) {
        case Message::Chat:
            os << "Chat";
            break;
        case Message::Error:
            os << "Error";
            break;
        case Message::Groupchat:
            os << "Groupchat";
            break;
        case Message::Headline:
            os << "Headline";
            break;
        case Message::Normal:
            os << "Normal";
            break;
        case Message::Invalid:
            os << "Invalid";
            break;
        default:
            os << "unknown type";
            break;
    }
return os;
}

ostream& operator<<(ostream& os, const Message& stanza) {
    os << "type:'" << stanza.subtype() <<  "' from:'" << stanza.from().full() << "' body:'" << stanza.body() << "'";
    return os;
}

class Bot : public MessageHandler,
            /*public PresenceHandler,*/
            public ConnectionListener
            /*,public RosterListener*/{
 public:
   Bot(){
      JID jid( "mmaaria123@gmail.com/home" );
      client = new Client( jid, "mmaaria123" );
      client->registerConnectionListener( this );
      client->registerMessageHandler( this );
      client->connect(true);
   }

    virtual void onConnect() {
        cout << "It is connected good:)"  << endl;
        //sleep(5);
        client->disconnect();
    }

    virtual void onDisconnect(ConnectionError e) {
        cout << "ConnListener::onDisconnect() " << endl;
    }

    virtual bool onTLSConnect(const CertInfo& Info) {

       time_t tm = Info.date_from;
       time_t tm_to = Info.date_to;
       cout << "\t Certificate information to " << LOGIN << endl;
       cout << "\t========================================" << endl;
      // number code << "\tServer status: " << Info.status;
        if (Info.status !=0)
            {
            cout << "\t !!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!" << endl;
            cout << "\t !!!  The certificate has a problem !!!" << endl;
            cout << "\t !!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!" << endl;
            // parsing binary Status Cert
            if ((CertInvalid) & Info.status)
                {
                    cout << "\t- The certificate is not trusted " << endl;
                }
            if (( CertSignerUnknown) & Info.status)
                {
                    cout << "\t- The certificate hasn't got a kown issuer" << endl;
                }
            if ((CertRevoked) & Info.status)
                {
                    cout << "\t- The certificate has been revoked " << endl;
                }
            if ((CertExpired) & Info.status)
                {
                    cout << "\t- The certificate has expired " << endl;
                }
            if ((CertNotActive) & Info.status)
                {
                    cout << "\t- The certificate is not yet active " << endl;
                }
            if ((CertWrongPeer) & Info.status)
                {
                    cout << "\t- The certificate has not issued for the peer we're connected to " << endl;
                }
            if ((CertSignerNotCa) & Info.status)
                {
                    cout << "\t- The signer is not CA " << endl;
                }
            cout << endl;
            }
            // end parsing
        else
            // if Info.status=0 sertificate is valide
            cout << " *** Cert is OK!" << endl;

       cout << "\tChain: " << Info.chain << endl;
       cout << "\tIssuer: " << Info.issuer << endl;
       cout << "\tServer: " << Info.server << endl;
       cout << "\tCert date from: " << ctime(&tm);
       cout << "\tCert date to: " << ctime(&tm_to);
       cout << "\tProtocol: " << Info.protocol << endl;
       cout << "\tCipher: " << Info.cipher << endl;
       cout << "\tMAC: " << Info.mac << endl;
       cout << "\tCompression: " << Info.compression << endl;
       cout << "\t========================================" << endl;
     return true;

    }

   virtual void handleMessage( const Message& stanza,
                               MessageSession* session = 0 ){
     Message msg(Message::Chat, stanza.from(), "hello world" );
     client->send( msg );
   }

 private:
   Client* client;
};

int main( int argc, char* argv[] ){
    cout << "1" << endl;
    Bot b;
}
```

Comment: Normalmente los errores tipo `undefined reference` se deben a problemas de enlazado. Seguramente ssl dispone de una carpeta con binarios cuya que tendrás que especificar para el linker.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lo que tienes es un error de linkado, no de compilación.

Antes que nada, debes tener claro donde tienes la librería ssl instalada y el nombre de la misma.

En CodeBlocks tienes que ir a Project->Build options...->Search directories->Linker y añadir aqui el directorio donde estén las dll instaladas.

También en el mismo dialogo pero en Linker settings->Link libraries deberás añadir el nombre de los ficheros dll que tengas en el directorio que especificaste antes.

Con esto CodeBlocks debería ser capaz de montar la linea de linkado correcta.